# Custom login page for Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, branding, azure-active-directory

I'm working on an application that uses Azure AD as an identity provider. It works well, but the login experience is jarring when the user is taken from my application to the [https://login.microsoftonline.com](https://login.microsoftonline.com/) Azure hosted login page. In addition to losing all application branding, the user is unlikely to know that the tenant domain suffix must be appended to their username when entering credentials (e.g. `bob` becomes `bob@mytenant.onmicrosoft.com`). Is there any way of hosting a login page for Azure AD within my own application?

Comment: Ben, have you found a solution to this problem ?  Wez also have the problem that froma customer's point of view, they have a personal account in our application, with no concept of an account in Azure.  And they thus not expect to be taken to a page with different look and feel.

Comment: We ended up hosting our own identity provider using ThinkTecture's IdentityServer, but it looks like there's at least basic customization available now through Azure.

Comment: Good alternative is Auth0. We are looking at it ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Custom company branding is now available with Azure Active Directory Basic and Premium editions. You can customize some of the experience, with some text, images and logos.

- [Azure Active Directory Editions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn532272.aspx)
- [Add company branding to your Sign In and Access Panel pages](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn532270.aspx)

Comment: Having many users (above 500.000) this becomes unfeasible - at a price of approx. 5 USD per user per month (a quote we received).

Comment: I'm pretty sure only the admin(s) who set up tenant branding are required to have an AAD Premium license, and they can enable it for the entire tenant.

Comment: Tenant branding is now available with Azure Active Directory Basic, which should be available at a lower price than AAD Premium.

Comment: That sounds good. Will they also allow any emails (eg. a gmail) to be used for login? Thats the last hurdle in the login flow. Sending a hint with a autogenerated MS/AD domain email is not pretty :/

Comment: For a single-tenant application, Microsoft Accounts (aka LiveIDs) will work if the user is a member of the tenant--and an MSA can use any email address they want. At this moment, the only way to add an MSA to a tenant is manually via the Azure portal.

Answer (score 5):

No. You cannot either host login page, nor customize the login page of Azure AD.

The only login page that you can change/host/customize is the one of the Access Control Service. And this is because ACS acts as `Federation Provider`, not as Identity Provider. And this is for security reasons.

What you may try is explore the [OAuth 2.0 Resource's Owner Password Flow](http://techblog.hybris.com/2012/06/11/oauth2-resource-owner-password-flow/) with AAD. However I never advise clients doing so for Web Applications.

If you are going to use AAD as a `one-and-only-one` Identity Provider for your web application. And you will be managing all the sign-up, password expiry, password reset, etc. flows with AAD. And you want a total customization of the login page - I will suggest that you take a look at the [Identity Server](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2). Use management in this product is probably easier, and you can customize login page. And you will maintain the service.

Comment: Thanks; I thought this might be the case. Do you know if there are any plans to incorporate at least basic customization of the login experience on a tenant by tenant basis? (logo images, text snippets, etc.)

Comment: Tak a look around you. Can you customize login page for Google for instance? Or Yahoo? Or Twitter? or Facebook? I don't expect `any` of these to allow customization of login pages. This is the idea of `federated` login. Users `trust` Facebook for instance. The moment you touch the login page, you lose customer's trust. I know and agree that having `your own` tenant in `AAD` is slightly different then having a `Facebook application`, but the security concept is the same.

Comment: In this case, I think I would be more likely to lose the customer's trust by presenting the AAD login page. From their perspective, they have a personal account in _my_ application, with no concept of an organizational account or Azure. I'll check out some of the other options you presented.

Comment: If your account is synced from a local AD, you can set it up as Federated and use your own ADFS instance, which you could then customize (to some extent; even in this flow users start on the MSOnline page). If you're not federated, you're stuck with the MicrosoftOnline login experience.

Comment: Good point Oren, however I believe the user wants to use AAD as Identity Provider for a Web Application without the hassle of maintaining local AD. I see this scenario more and more since the GA of AAD.

Answer (score 1):

If the customization options offered by Azure Active Directory Premium isn't enough, you can deploy your own ADFS server and fully customize the sign in process.

[Follow the instructions here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn441213.aspx) to implement your own ADFS server with Azure.  This will offer the added benefit of enhanced security and policy options.