# Can I use Azure AD B2C in my own login/registration page(MVC)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

I came across this link: [Custom login page for Azure Active Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17935577/custom-login-page-for-azure-active-directory) which specifies that I can not use AAD B2C with a custom page... As currently it sends you straight to their login/registration page, I lose my branding completely.

Is this still the case ? I've tried researching but can not find anything. Everything points to how to use AAD B2C and redirecting to their login/registration page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I use Azure AD B2C in my own login/registration page(MVC)?

No, today that's not an option.

AAD B2C will redirect you to their login/registration page.

Having said that, you can edit the custom CSS for that screen, find some documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-ui-customization) and a helper tool [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-ui-customization-helper-tool).

Find [here](https://wingtipgamesb2c.azurewebsites.net/) an example of above customization.

There is also another feature for [language customization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-language-customization).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I thought that was the case, Thanks for providing the links. I have looked at the helper tool, but have not tried it yet. I have marked yours as the answer as you theoretically answered what I was asking for :)